# Latest 22.04 Ubuntu version installed but UI and new things not updated

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I have updated Ubuntu from 16 version to 18 → 20 → 22, then Settings → Overview page showing Ubuntu 22.04 without LTS, but rest of UI of Ubuntu 16

[image]

I need this look

[image]

Comment: Do a fresh install of 22.04. It is too long upgrade path to be perfect.

Comment: I disagree. I've done all those upgrades, there's no reason it should be different if done all at the same time. And nobody should have to do a complete reinstall. The times I've done that have been more trouble than they're worth with the need to reinstall all apps and restore data.
Please fix your links -- they both point to the same image and "enter image description here" is not helpful. Please explain what you think is wrong (I'm a kubuntu user; that image looks perfectly normal to me, but I'm not remotely sure what it _should_ look like).